# how to send mail from group email in script task ssis

Tags: ssis, etl, sendmail

I want to send email from SSIS. To do this I am using script task and inside that, i am using below code and same is working very well.

Now my manager told me to send mail from team_dev@uhg.com instead of hieko@uhg.com.I this case what would be my password as team_dev@uhg.com is group email.

```
email.From = new MailAddress("hieko@uhg.com");
email.To.Add("team_testing@uhg.com");
email.Subject = "Test Mail";
email.Body = "This Email is coming from SSIS Script Task";


try
  {
     MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
     SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("alaska");
     // START
     email.From = new MailAddress(SendMailFrom);
     email.To.Add(SendMailTo);
     email.Subject = SendMailSubject;
     email.Body = SendMailBody;
     //END

     SmtpServer.Port = 25;
     SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SendMailFrom, "my password");
     SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

     SmtpServer.Send(email);
     MessageBox.Show("Email was Successfully Sent ");
  }
catch (Exception ex)
  {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
  }
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Comment: What happens if you just change the address in the `email.From` line, but keep your email and password in the Credentials?

Comment: I will check it and let you know.But what is the correct way to do it?I cannot take risk of being rejected by the client by doing workaround here.

Comment: You probably need to ask service desk or someone responsible for the user accounts to give you the credentials for the account that should be sending the emails. It's not a good idea hard code your own credentials

Comment: Thanks. I will check with the service desk.